# CFDictionary won't bridge to NSDictionary (Swift 2.0 / iOS9)

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, swift2, toll-free-bridging, cfdictionary

OK, this is a case I came across when working with CGImageSource and noticed that the toll-free-bridging between CFDictionary and NSDictionary seems to run into problems in certain cases. I've managed to construct the below example to show what I mean:

```
func optionalProblemDictionary() -> CFDictionary? {
    let key = "key"
    let value = "value"
    var keyCallBacks = CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks()
    var valueCallBacks = CFDictionaryValueCallBacks()

    let cfDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(key)), UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(value)), 1, &keyCallBacks, &valueCallBacks)
    return cfDictionary
}
```

Fairly straightforward (and a bit silly) but its a function returning and optional CFDictionary. The "fun" starts when trying to create an NSDictionary from this function:

Why won't the following work?

```
if let problemDictionary = optionalProblemDictionary() as? NSDictionary {
    print(problemDictionary) // never enters, no warnings, compiles just fine
}
```

While this works fine?

```
if let cfDictionary = optionalProblemDictionary() {
    let problemDictionary = cfDictionary as NSDictionary
    print(problemDictionary)
}
```

XCode 7.0 (7A220)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason seems to be that the function returns an *optional*
`CFDictionary?` and that can not be cast to a (non-optional)
`NSDictionary`.

Here is a simpler example demonstrating the same problem with `CFString` vs `NSString`:

```
let cfString = "foobar" as CFString?

if let s1 = cfString as? NSString {
    print("s1 = \(s1)") // not executed
}
```

(The question remains why this does not give a compiler error or
at least a compiler warning because this optional cast can
*never* succeed.)

But a casting to an optional `NSString?` works:

```
if let s2 = cfString as NSString? {
    print("s2 = \(s2)") // prints "s2 = foobar"
}
```

In your case, if you change the "problematic case" to

```
if let problemDictionary = cfDict as NSDictionary? {
    print(problemDictionary)
}
```

then the if-block is executed.

---

Note that your method to build a `CFDictionary` in Swift is not correct
and actually caused program crashes in my test. One reason is that
the dictionary callbacks are set to empty structures.
Another problem is that `unsafeAddressOf(key)` bridges  the Swift
string to an `NSString` which can be deallocated immediately.

I don't know what the best method is to build a `CFDictionary` in Swift,
but this worked in my test:

```
func optionalProblemDictionary() -> CFDictionary? {

    let key = "key" as NSString 
    let value = "value" as NSString

    var keys = [ unsafeAddressOf(key) ]
    var values = [ unsafeAddressOf(value) ]

    var keyCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
    var valueCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks

    let cfDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &keys, &values, 1, &keyCallBacks, &valueCallBacks)
    return cfDictionary
}
```

Comment: It does not answer to the question - how to convert to NSDictionary.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov: I think it does: `if let problemDictionary = cfDict as NSDictionary? { ... }` casts the CFDictionary? to NSDictionary?, and uses optional binding to unwrap that to NSDictionary. Please let me know which information exactly you are missing.

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot. The result of the cast is nil - http://www.screencast.com/t/hbjhDzCs0K

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov: Did you try to replace `let options = attachments as? NSDictionary` by `let options = attachments as NSDictionary?`, as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov: Any feedback?

Comment: This worked for me (1 line): `let txtdict: CFDictionary = ["role":"Server"]`

Comment: @xaphod i tried taking that approach and got an error `Contextual type 'CFDictionary' cannot be used with dictionary literal`